# Strange exception when connecting to a WCF service via a proxy server

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

The exception "**This operation is not supported for a relative URI.**" occurs in the following situation:

I have a WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.None)]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyFault))]
    List<MyDto> MyOperation(int param);

    // other operations
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public List<MyDto> MyOperation(int param)
    {
        // Do the business stuff and return a list of MyDto
    }

    // other implementations
}
```

`MyFault` and `MyDto` are two very simple classes marked with `[DataContract]` attribute and each only having three `[DataMember]` of type `string, int and int?`.

This service is hosted in IIS 7.0 on a Win 2008 Server along with an ASP.NET application. I am using an SVC file `MyService.svc` which is located directly in the root of the web site. The service configuration in web.config is the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MyServiceLib.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig" 
          contract="MyServiceLib.IMyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig">
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This seems to work so far as I can enter the address http://www.domain.com/MyService.svc in a browser and get the "This is a Windows Communication Foundation Service"-Welcome page.

One of the clients consuming the service is a console application:

```
MyServiceClient aChannel = new MyServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IMyService");
List<MyDto> aMyDtoList = aChannel.MyOperation(1);
```

It has the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="true" transactionFlow="false"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false"
          proxyAddress="10.20.30.40:8080" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
              maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
                negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.domain.com/MyService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService"
          contract="MyService.IMyService"
          name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I run this application at a production server at a customer site calling `aChannel.MyOperation(1)` throws the following exception:

**This operation is not supported for a relative URI.**

When I run this client application on my development PC with exactly the same config, **with the exception that I remove `proxyAddress="10.20.30.40:8080"` from the bindings** the operation works without problems.

Now I really don't know **what specifying a proxy server address might have to do with absolute or relative URIs**. The use of the proxy server or not is the only difference I can see when running the client on the production or on the development machine.

Does someone have an idea what this exception might mean in this context and how possibly to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance for help!

**Edit:**

In case it should be important: Service and Client are built with WCF in **.NET Framework 4**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`10.20.30.40:8080` is not a valid URL. You want `http://10.20.30.40:8080`.

---

Here's my diagnostic thought process, in case it helps anyone:

1. Exceptions don't usually lie. They usually mean just exactly what they say. The trick is to understand how they could possibly be telling the truth.
2. The exception said, "This operation is not supported for a relative URI". If that were true, then it meant that an operation was being performed, it was being given a relative URL, but it doesn't support relative URIs.
3. The OP then said that when he runs the application "with the exception that I remove proxyAddress="10.20.30.40:8080" from the bindings".

There, in front of me, was a relative URI. When he removed it, the "operation" worked, so I deduced that this was the relative URI that was supplied to the "operation" that doesn't support them.

You don't exactly have to be Sherlock Holmes to solve this one. The key was being able to instantly see that there was no `scheme://` in front of the URI, making it relative.

Comment: Wow! A thousand pages long question, one line of answer and you hit the nail. Just tested, works, marked as answer. I hide in shame. Anyway: Good that I asked. Thank you very much! (Edit: Lol, "you can accept an answer in 2 minutes", you were too fast. Waiting now 2 minutes...)

Comment: Slauma, it's very good that you've asked! )) Because I got caught in very similar situation. The reason why proxy URL was used without "http://" in my case is that it was copied from another place (parameter to wget.exe) where it was a legitimate syntax.